# How to get view expose filter input inside a panel?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views, panels

I have crated a panel with a content pane and expose filter block.
Both works well.

Problem is that if i create a filter using "Simple hierarchical select" widget for taxonomy term. 
i am not able to get the term id expose filter input;

I am alter the expose filter:

```
function utility_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state,$form_id){
    dpm($form_state['input']);
    array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'manage_custom_filters');
}
function manage_custom_filters($form, &$form_state) {
  //modify form_state values of concerned field
  $form_state['values']['shs_term_node_tid_depth'] = '91';
  //modify form_state of concerned field to pass to the view
  $form_state['view']->display_handler->handlers['filter']['shs_term_node_tid_depth']->validated_exposed_input = '91';
}
```

Comment: That hook doesn't look like it's named correctly. Is it being called? Just put in a `drupal_set_message("Hi from utility_form_views_exposed_form_alter");` to check. Is the widget displaying on the Panels page with the View?

Comment: yes it is calling. widget is displaying on panel page&working on other page.

Comment: i have made the changes by putting some constant value of tid and its filter.